# Reduce the disk space required while streaming

Tags: streaming, sd-card, video-streaming, raspberry-pi

My plan is that I'm going to use a 8GB SD-card for my Raspberry PI. The PI itself will not store much more then the actual OS and its components, but will instead **gather all required files from different sources across the local network**.

Say I'd like to stream a 720p / 1080p movie. That'd probably **need more** than the ~5-6GB available - which is causing my question:
How to reduce the disk space required while streaming? Only **storing the current part** of the movie and **deleting viewed parts** is a way that comes to my mind.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to this in reality, or other ways to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Appreciating all input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

Suppose you have the video in the remote mounted `/mnt`

In `/mnt` you can start a [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)

```
cd /mnt
mkfifo movii
cat your_movie > movii
```

Just `cd` to your `$HOME` and you can watch the video with

```
cat movii | mplayer -- -
```

Hope this answers your question.